# much and more comparative superlative

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

I know that *much* is used with uncountable nouns and *more* with countable nouns.

There is no connection between *much* and *more* with the comparative and superlative, right?

For example, if we take the word *better*, what would be its corresponding comparative and superlative forms?

Comparative would be *much better*, but what is the superlative? Is it *most better*?

Also, is it same with *more* when talking about its own respective comparative and superlative forms?

Answer (score 6):

You have many things wrong here. *Many* goes with count nouns, *much* with mass nouns, and both share the same comparative and superlatives.

***many/more/most***:

- I have many friends.
- I have more friends.
- I have the most friends.

***much/more/most***:

- I have much interest.
- I have more interest.
- I have the most interest.

As for *better*, it is already the comparative degree of both *good* and *well*.

***good/better/best***:

- She is a good singer.
- She is a/the better singer.
- She is the best singer.

***well/better/best***

- She sings well.
- She sings better.
- She sings best.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed many people confused while using 'well' as an adverb, most of them says I'll try my level best considering 'best' to be an adjective for noun 'level' instead of it being an 'adverb' for the verb 'try'