# Why do we have different words for countable/uncountable quantity in the decreasing direction but not the increasing direction?

Tags: grammatical-number, antonyms

Why do we differentiate between "fewer" for a countable quantity and "less" for an uncountable one but not between countable and uncountable quantities for "more"? Is there an archaic distinction that has fallen out of usage? Or am I just daft and overlooking a simple one?

Comment: This is relevant, although doesn't answer the question why: [much and more comparative superlative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/much-and-more-comparative-superlative)

Comment: Good question, although note that in English *less* has always been used with countable things as well as uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

I think "many" and "much" have a similar relationship in terms of countable and uncountable and they have a relatively strong connection to the idea of more of something or a lot of something.

Comment: *Many* and *much* do have the countable/uncountable thing covered, but neither of them means *more*.